# Some problems were found with the configuration of task , No value has been specified for property 'signingConfig.keyAlias'. flutter

Tags: flutter

[build gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYpVv.png)

[build gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au2T6.png)

[build gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIZfy.png)

[key.Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjqsQ.png)

Comment: * What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:signingConfigWriterRelease'.
> No value has been specified for property 'signingConfig.keyAlias'.
> No value has been specified for property 'signingConfig.keyPassword'.
> No value has been specified for property 'signingConfig.storePassword'.      this is the error

Comment: May you please copy and paste your build.gradle and key.properties files into a code block? @Yassin_ghobara

Comment: @Benjamin you will find the photos of the build gradle and key. Properties in the question .

Answer (score 0):

You have put your actual key alias name and password in your `build.gradle` file, those are just the keys, not the values. Do this instead.

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
```

And also, since you're using windows, use two backslashes in your key location, like this.

````
storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=key
storeFile=C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Desktop\\key.jks```// change this to your key's location, but WITH the two backslashes
````

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Failed to read key recipe from store "B:\recipe_app\android\app\recipe_app\android\app\KeyStore\recipe.keystore": No key with alias 'recipe' found in keystore B:\recipe_app\android\app\recipe_app\android\app\KeyStore\recipe.keystore

Comment: you forgot using the extension name and double backslashes

Comment: First add those, then run Flutter Clean, then build the project

Comment: storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=recipe
storeFile=B://KeyStore//recipe.keystore

Comment: like this? then run flutter clean in the terminal/

Comment: yup and add the extentions too, like recipe.keystore.jks

Comment: i have made all of what you said and make a a new keystore  and here is my key .properties storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=keystore
storeFile=B://KeyStore//keystore.jks

Comment: and i stil get this error * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Failed to read key keystore from store "B:\KeyStore\keystore.jks": No key with alias 'keystore' found in keystore B:\KeyStore\keystore.jks

Comment: Did u created the keystore using 'keystore' as the alias?

Comment: You're welcome bro, please accept it as the answer and upvote if it helped :)